# Invisible Outbound Change Sets In scratch and in organization

Tags: community, salesforcedx, salesforce1-app, workflowoutboundmessage

Messing Outbound Change Sets in the scratch and in the organization Account too.
Could anyone please let me know how to get the "outbound changeset" in scratch? Your help is greatly appreciated.

This is scratch
[image]

This organization account
[image]

Comment: Is this a Scratch Org, or a Sandbox? They are two different things.

Comment: Both are the same I have tried srtach then also not showing out Outbound Change Sets in the setup

Comment: Scratch Orgs **do not** have Change Sets, but Sandboxes **do** have Change Sets.

Comment: I have used only in scratch but unable to view Outbound Change Sets

Answer (score 3):

Scratch Orgs do not have Change Sets, because they are not linked to your production org as Sandboxes are. If you don't see Change Sets in your production account, you do not have administrative access to this feature, or your production org doesn't have Sandbox licenses, so you'd need to contact your administrator or Sales.